# Обойти точку при построении пешеходного маршрута Yandex maps

Tags: yandex-maps-api

подскажите как я могу при прокладке пешеходного маршрута обходить некоторые точки. То есть выбирать маршрут, проходящий мимо этих точек? использую JS API, Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нужно уточнить, что значит "обходить точки"? Вообще WayPoints любого маршрута можно редактировать вручную, в песочнице есть такой пример:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
            center: [57.131311, 34.576128],
            zoom: 5
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        // Признак начала редактирования маршрута.
        startEditing = false,
        button = $('#editor');

    // Построение маршрута от станции метро Смоленская до станции Третьяковская.
    // Маршрут должен проходить через метро "Арбатская".
    ymaps.route([
        'Москва, метро Смоленская',
        {
            // Метро Арбатская - транзитная точка (проезжать через эту точку,
            // но не останавливаться в ней).
            type: 'viaPoint',
            point: 'Москва, метро Арбатская'
        },
        // Метро "Третьяковская".
        [55.744568, 37.60118]
    ], {
        // Автоматически позиционировать карту.
        mapStateAutoApply: true
    }).then(function (route) {
        myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
        button.click(function () {
            if (startEditing = !startEditing) {
                // Включаем редактор.
                route.editor.start({addWayPoints: true, removeWayPoints: true});
                button.text('Отключить редактор маршрута');
            } else {
                // Выключаем редактор.
                route.editor.stop();
                button.text('Включить редактор маршрута');
            }
        });
        route.editor.events.add(["waypointadd", "waypointremove", "start"], function () {
            if (route.getWayPoints().getLength() >= 10) {
                // Если на карте больше 9 точек маршрута, отключаем добавление новых точек.
                route.editor.start({addWayPoints: false, removeWayPoints: true});
            }
            else {
                // Включаем добавление новых точек.
                route.editor.start({addWayPoints: true, removeWayPoints: true});
            }
        })
    }, function (error) {
        alert("Возникла ошибка: " + error.message);
    });
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=03a877a3-1510-48f0-b553-e57406abfea8&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="router_editor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style>
        html, body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        #map {
            width: 100%;
            height: 90%;
        }

        #editor {
            padding: 4px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <button value="Включить редактор маршрута" id="editor" name="start">Включить редактор маршрута</button>
</body>

</html>
```